# Calendar object in Expression language

Tags: java, jsp, el

How do i get day, month and year (and every Calendar.XXXXXXX value) in expression language?

```
${object.calendarObject.MONTH}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`${calendar.time}`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getTime%28%29) to get a [`Date`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) object in EL. You can use [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) [`<fmt:formatDate>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fmt/formatDate.html) to format a `Date` object into a human readable string in JSP. It uses [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) under the covers and supports also all of its patterns by the `pattern` attribute.

In below examples I assume for brevity that `${cal}` is the calendar. Substitute it with your `${object.calendarObject}` whenever applicable.

```xml
<%@taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
...
<ul>
  <li>Standard date/time: <fmt:formatDate value="${cal.time}" type="both" /></li>
  <li>Standard date: <fmt:formatDate value="${cal.time}" type="date" /></li>
  <li>Day: <fmt:formatDate value="${cal.time}" pattern="d" /></li>
  <li>Month: <fmt:formatDate value="${cal.time}" pattern="M" /></li>
  <li>Year: <fmt:formatDate value="${cal.time}" pattern="yyyy" /></li>
  <li>dd-MM-yyyy: <fmt:formatDate value="${cal.time}" pattern="dd-MM-yyyy" /></li>
  <li>MM/dd/yyyy: <fmt:formatDate value="${cal.time}" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" /></li>
</ul>
```

As of now this should yield something like (English locale, GMT+1):

> - Standard date/time: Jul 6, 2011 10:34:17 PM
> - Standard date: Jul 6, 2011
> - Day: 6
> - Month: 7
> - Year: 2011
> - dd-MM-yyyy: 06-07-2011
> - MM/dd/yyyy: 07/06/2011

Comment: +1 I know this is a worthless comment and I'll be completely fine with it being deleted, but @BalusC, you are awesome! Whenever I have a question about scriptless JSPs, I look for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can't directly with the calendar object, you can create a wrapper for the Calendar object with getters methods like these:

```
public int getMonth(){
    wrappedCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
}
public int getDay(){
    wrappedCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
}
public int getYear(){
    wrappedCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
}
...
```

So you could use on your expression language something like this:

```
${calWrapper.month}/${calWrapper.day}/${calWrapper.year}
```